# Tile count background

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications

I have WCF service, that send Tile notification with Count to windows phone emulator, but I think that this Count has white color and background for this number has white color too in emulator, so I see only white space. Is there any possibility to set number or background different color?

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears only in emulator on a computer without `DirectX 10`. On a device `Count` will be visible without any problem